# How to adapt Mashape application key in Swift?

Tags: ios, api, swift, mashape

I tried to use "Yoda Speak" API by Mashape.
I got binary data but I don't know how to parse the data.
When I try to print the data, I got this message.
"(message, Missing Mashape application key. Go to https://www.mashape.com to get your key.)"
I think the Mashape application key is "jY0bEhHCBpmsh8j1mpA5p11tCJGyp1tok3Zjsn4ubbvNNp5Jt3".

How to adapt this key in Swift?

```
    func response(res: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) {

    let json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    let header: NSDictionary = ["X-Mashape-Key" : "jY0bEhHCBpmsh8j1mpA5p11tCJGyp1tok3Zjsn4ubbvNNp5Jt3"]

    for value in json {
        println(value)
    }
}

func getData() {
   let url = NSURL(string: "https://yoda.p.mashape.com/yoda?sentence=I+like+you")!
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: req, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(req, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: response)
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have a mistake.
I couldn't get binary data.
I got only the message "message, Missing Mashape application key. Go to https://www.mashape.com to get your key."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `X-Mashape-Key` as a header to your `NSURLRequest`. To do so:

```
let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
req.setValue("jY0bEhHCBpmsh8j1mpA5p11tCJGyp1tok3Zjsn4ubbvNNp5Jt3", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(req, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: response)
```

Should do the trick. You can then remove the header `NSDictionary` from your response handler as it is of no use.

Comment: Thank you so much! I could set header!